# logstash 7.9.1 docker conatiner: file input is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I am trying to read a log file but is not working, it works when the logstash.conf is configure to listen in the port 5000 but from a file not works. I am using logstash version 7.9.1 from docker container and trying to sent the logs to Elastic search 7.9.1.
This is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/home/douglas/projects/incollect/*.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "test-elk-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

this is the logs from the console,I can't see any error and says Successfully started

```
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:27,748][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:27,795][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:27,798][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x44d5fe run>"}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:27,800][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4c6dee32 run>"}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:27,840][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,535][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.73}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,599][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,600][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.8}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,840][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,909][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:".monitoring-logstash", :main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:28,920][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][4a3eb924128694e00dae8e6fab084bfc5e3c3692e66663362019b182fcb31a48] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
logstash_1       | [2020-10-16T00:38:29,386][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

and this is my log file:

```
Oct  9 15:34:19 incollect drupal: http://dev.incollect.com|1602257659|DEV|52.202.31.67|http://dev.incollect.com/icadmin/inquires_report?q=icadmin/ajax_validate_and_fix_inquire_by_id|http://dev.incollect.com/icadmin/inquires_report|3||Validate inquireStep 0 
Oct  9 15:34:19 incollect drupal: http://dev.incollect.com|1602257659|DEV|52.202.31.67|http://dev.incollect.com/icadmin/inquires_report?q=icadmin/ajax_validate_and_fix_inquire_by_id|http://dev.incollect.com/icadmin/inquires_report|3||Validate inquireStep 1 - inquire_id:14219
```

*********************Edited*************************************
I am adding the docker-compose file, this is my configuration to logstash

```
logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    volumes:
      - ./../../:/usr/share/logstash
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

I am not sure what is the problem, I tried differents solutions but it does not works.

Comment: Does the path `/home/douglas/projects/incollect/` exists inside your docker container?

Comment: No, is the phisical path of the log? should I create it?

Comment: If the path does not exist, logstash has nothing to read. If you are running logstash in a docker container, then the file input can read only the files that exist **inside** the container, it won't read anything outside unless you expose the local volume to the container.

Comment: the path exist and I mounted the volume in order that the container can read the log file but it does not work.

Comment: How did you mounted it? Are you using docker compose? Update your question explaning how you are starting your container. Also, remove the `ignore_older => 0` option, this will make logstash ignore everything that is older than **0 seconds**.

Answer (score 1):

If this is  `- ./../../:/usr/share/logstash` what you are using to mount the logs volume, your logstash file input path should point to `/usr/share/logstash/*.log`